# python lxml xml.etree.ElementTree.Element to string will not convert

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

```
    type(ikePanProfiles)
    <class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>

    etree.tostring(ikePanProfiles)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
     File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3367, in lxml.etree.tostring 
    (src/lxml/etree.c:82622)
    TypeError: Type 'Element' cannot be serialized.
```

I'm accessing an API that responds in kind with an object type of "xml.etree.ElementTree.Element" So I'm not sure how to covert this tostring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element is an object from the `xml` library and you are trying to use `lxml` to stringify it. Either change your code so that your element is an object from the `lxml` library, or use `xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring` to stringify it.

Comment: using xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(ikePanProfiles) worked. Thanks. I don't have control over what the element object is from the API.